# Remove last word in a string in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

What is the most efficient way to split a string into two parts, in the following way

One part is the last word of string that follows last whitespace character in the string
Second part is rest of the string

e.g.
"This is a sentence"
one part: "sentence"
second part: "This is a " //Note there is whitespace at the end of this string

"This is a "
one part: ""
second part: "This is a "

Comment: Take a look at Barry's answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752946/how-to-get-the-first-n-words-from-a-nsstring-in-objective-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want to remove the last word, semantically speaking, or do you want to chop everything off after the last whitespace character, which is what you described? I'm asking because they're not actually the same thing, depending on the language of the text.

If you want to chop off everything after the last bit of whitespace, the other answers here will do you fine. But if you want to chop off the last word, then you need to dig a little deeper and use the word enumeration APIs:

```
NSString *removeLastWord(NSString *str) {
    __block NSRange lastWordRange = NSMakeRange([str length], 0);
    NSStringEnumerationOptions opts = NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationReverse | NSStringEnumerationSubstringNotRequired;
    [str enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) options:opts usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        lastWordRange = substringRange;
        *stop = YES;
    }];
    return [str substringToIndex:lastWordRange.location];
}
```

Comment: +1. Do you need to include NSStringEnumerationLocalized, though, to get the locale-specific word boundaries?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was looking to chop off everything after last whitespace(newLine) character

Comment: @JesseRusak: The description for that constant says it uses the user's locale. Presumably, leaving it off means it auto-detects the locale from the text.

Answer (score 18):

Try something like this:

```
NSString *str = @"this is a sentence";

// Search from back to get the last space character
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString: @" " options: NSBackwardsSearch];

// Take the first substring: from 0 to the space character
NSString *str1 = [str substringToIndex: range.location]; // @"this is a" 

// take the second substring: from after the space to the end of the string
NSString *str2 = [str substringFromIndex: range.location +1];  // @"sentence"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]` and `-[NSArray componentsJoinedByString:]` to split a string into individual components (words) and back again:

```
NSString *sentence = @"This is a sentence";
NSLog(@"Sentence: \"%@\"", sentence);
NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
sentence = [sentence stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];

NSMutableArray *words = [[sentence componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:whitespace] mutableCopy];
NSString *lastWord = [words lastObject];
[words removeLastObject];
NSString *firstPart = [words componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

NSLog(@"Last word: \"%@\" First part: \"%@\"", lastWord, firstPart);
```

Output:

```
2013-01-07 18:36:50.566 LastWord[42999:707] Sentence: "This is a sentence"
2013-01-07 18:36:50.569 LastWord[42999:707] Last word: "sentence" First part: "This is a"
```

This code assumes a few things to be aware of. First, it trims whitespace you mentioned off the beginning/end of the sentence, but doesn't preserve it. So if that whitespace is actually important to you, you'll have to account for. Also, it doesn't do anything special if the sentence is empty or only contains one word (it's safe this way, just not particularly sophisticated).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to achieve the above by handling both whitespace and new line characters, instead of just whitespace

Comment: Yes, there is. Change `NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];` to `NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];`